# CVE-2022-42889 vulnerability

Tags: wso2-api-manager

This is regarding the CVE-2022-42889 vulnerability. From the below documentation link its mentioned that

"However we are actively working on upgrading the vulnerable dependency version to non-vulnerable version to reduce the unnecessary noise made by the Software Composition Analysis scanners. Customers may apply the security update once it is available. "

https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/CVE-2022-42889

We wanted to know if there is any ETA for the vulnerable jars to be removed from WSO2 products.

Thanks,
Navaneeth

Security vulnerability. security tools are reporting the jar as vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing effort the WSO2 API Manager versions and the update will be released within next couple of weeks.